# Using constants in constructor

Tags: python, class, constructor, constants

I am getting an error when I try to use a constant inside a constructor in a class.  I have searched for a resolution to the issue all morning and I can make the program function by using if/else statements in the getter but the instructions are to use the constants.

```
class Fan:

    SLOW = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    FAST = 3

    def __init__(self, speed=SLOW, radius=5, color='blue', on=False):
        self.__speed = speed
        self.__on = on
        self.__radius = radius
        self.__color = color

    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.__speed

    def getRadius(self):
        return self.__radius

    def getColor(self):
        return self.__color

    def getOn(self):
        return self.__on

    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        self.__speed = speed

    def setRadius(self, radius):
        self.__radius = radius

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.__color = color

    def setOn(self, on):
        self.__on = on

fan1 = Fan(FAST, 10, 'yellow', True)
fan2 = Fan(MEDIUM, 5, 'blue', False)

print(fan1.getSpeed())
print(fan1.getRadius())
print(fan1.getColor())
print(fan1.getOn())
print()
print(fan2.getSpeed())
print(fan2.getRadius())
print(fan2.getColor())
print(fan2.getOn())
```

When I run this code I get the following error "NameError: name 'FAST' is not defined"

Any help and explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: These constants are class attributes, not globals, so you have to access them that way everywhere except within the class definition body.

Comment: Note that you don't need `Fan.SLOW` when *defining* `__init__` because at that point, `SLOW` is just a "local" variable at the same "scope" as the function definition. (Quotes used because class definitions are a bit quirky.)

Comment: As an aside, this looks like code written by a Java programmer that hasn't learned Python yet. None of those getters and setters would be used in idiomatic Python code; the attributes would just be used directly.

Comment: If you wanted more complex logic to wrap the simple attribute access, the right thing to do would be to define them as properties rather than simple instance attributes.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the information, the instruction requires use of getters and setters since I am still learning the fundamentals.  At least that's my theory since I have came across loads of information to write these programs differently (and more efficiently).

Comment: Ah, so you are being taught by someone who can't (or won't) distinguish between idiomatic Python and abstract object-oriented programming. My condolences.

Answer (score 3):

FAST does not exist in your main program.  It only exists in your class

you need to refer to FAST within the class

use `Fan.FAST` instead.

You'll probably also get an error when instantiating a Fan object with the default parameters unless you change `SLOW` to `Fan.SLOW`

Comment: The last sentence is false, as I explain in a comment to the question. (The fact that the script even *tries* to execute anything beyond the class definition demonstrates this.)

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
fan1 = Fan(Fan.FAST, 10, 'yellow', True)
fan2 = Fan(Fan.MEDIUM, 5, 'blue', False)
```

You need to add `Fan.` in front of `FAST` and `MEDIUM` because these constants are class variables, not global variables.